# Apply different css for different elements in a same class

Tags: css

I would like to know if it is possible to apply different css settings for different elements in the same class.

e.g. I have `<li>` and I want to apply different fore-colors to the #city, #state and #zipcode but I want to achieve this in the same class.

```
<li>
 <div id="city">    </div>
 <div id="state"> </div>    
 <div id="zipcode"></div>
</li>
```

I want something like -

```
.className{
     here is css for city;
     here is css for state;
     here is css for zipcode;
}
```

Comment: Apply specific styling for different ids. Adding styling inside classes isnt possible in css alone, but you could look into preprocessors like sass/scss or less.

Comment: Google `CSS :nth-child()`

Comment: different colors to different elements but in same selector? once think about it..

Answer (score 1):

I don't really know why you want to do things this way.

You could simply use the `id` selectors:

```
#city    { background-color: red;   }
#state   { background-color: green; }
#zipcode { background-color: blue;  }
```

If you want to specify by class then assuming your `<li>` has a class of `className` you can use a number of pseudo-selectors to access the children

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/8qAvb/

### HTML

```
<li class="className">
    <div id="city">city</div>
    <div id="state">state</div>
    <div id="other1">other1</div>
    <div id="other2">other2</div>
    <div id="other3">other3</div>
    <div id="other4">other4</div>
    <div id="zipcode">zipcode</div>
</li>
```

### CSS

```
.className > div {
    background-color: green;
}
.className > div:first-child {
    background-color: red;
}
.className > div:nth-child(3) {
    background-color: lime;
}
.className > div:nth-child(4) {
    background-color: pink;
}
.className > div:nth-child(5) {
    background-color: orange;
}
.className > div:last-child {
    background-color: blue;
}
```

Comment: I want to apply different themes for this set of <li> so I thought of I can create only one class with all css and use it. seems like its not possible with css. Thanks for your answer and time.